# DND 3.5e: Does offhand unarmed attack have full STR Adj?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monk, fighter, unarmed-combat

> #### Unarmed Strike
>
> At 1st level, a monk gains Improved Unarmed Strike as a bonus feat. A monk’s attacks may be with either fist interchangeably or even from elbows, knees, and feet. This means that a monk may even make unarmed strikes with her hands full. There is no such thing as an off-hand attack for a monk striking unarmed. A monk may thus apply her full Strength bonus on damage rolls for all her unarmed strikes.

As per described, it seems for monks (and probably for monks only), using two-weapon-fighting would allow the full STR Adj. to be applied to all of his attacks (flurry of blows, normal main hand attack, off-hand additional attack). Is that how it works?

Also, it seems this feature does not apply to a fighter who picks Improved Unarmed Strike as a bonus feat, but Power Attack specifically allows it to be applied to unarmed attack. So the damage bonus from Power Attack could be usable for a fighter who use unarmed attack for off-hand (though STR Adj. would still be halved)?

Comment: Just found an answer else where with a Q&A. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/191147/74669

Comment: Cool, thanks for finding the duplicate; I’ve marked it an “official” duplicate to make that clearer to folks and avoid splitting answers. By the way, please avoid code formatting (e.g. backticks) for non-code text (i.e. text intended to be read more by a human than a computer). It can cause accessibility issues. Bold or italics are acceptable if you must, but for what it’s worth, D&D 3.5e’s own style merely capitalized the names of feats.